# ANDROID OverlayItem - Pass Values

Tags: android, android-maps, android-mapview

Is it possible to send values other than marker, title and snippet in OverLayItem.
Because I want to handle many buttons when a balloon in map is clicked so I need extra values like IDs, status, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to create new class of overlayitem

```
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;

public class MyOverlayItem extends OverlayItem{

    public String newvalue;

        public MyOverlayItem (GeoPoint point,String arg1,String  arg2,String newvalue)
        {
            super(point, arg1, arg2);
            this.newvalue=newvalue;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass of course, OverlayItem is just like any other class, change its constructor and pass for it the values you need in the class.